# Spark UDF error - Schema for type Any is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I’m trying to create a udf that will replace negative values in a column with 0.

My dataframe is – called df, and contains one column called avg_x.
This is my code for creating a udf

```
val noNegative = udf {(avg_acc_x: Double) => if(avg_acc_x < 0) 0 else "avg_acc_x"}
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

df.printSchema returns

```
|-- avg_acc_x: double (nullable = false)
```

so I don’t understand why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because of the `else` returning a `String`: `"avg_acc_x"`. Take away the quotes:

```
val noNegative = udf {(avg_acc_x: Double) => if(avg_acc_x < 0) 0 else avg_acc_x}
```

Comment: I got very similar error when trying to serialize `mutable.Set` in Scala. Error was `Schema for type scala.collection.mutable.Set[MyType] is not supported`. Regular `Set` worked.

Answer (score 3):

This error basically occurs when the Analyzer cannot resolve the type of udf properly. That is, the types are mixed (Int and String).

Therefore,

`if(avg_acc_x < 0) 0 else avg_acc_x` (Integer Type)

or

`if(avg_acc_x < 0) "0" else "avg_acc_x"` (String Type)

should resolve this exception.