# Spark 2.1.0 UDF Schema type not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am using a data type called a Point(x: Double, y: Double). I am trying to using columns _c1 and _c2 as input to Point(), and then create a new column of Point values as follows

```
val toPoint = udf{(x: Double, y: Double) => Point(x,y)}
```

Then I call the function:

```
val point = data.withColumn("Point", toPoint(watned("c1"),wanted("c2")))
```

However, when I declare the udf I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point is not supported
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:733)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$2.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:729)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$2.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:728)
      at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
      at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
      at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
      at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
      at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:728)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:671)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3084)
      ... 48 elided
```

I have properly imported this data type, and used it many times before. Now that I try to include it in the Schema of my udf it doesn't recognize it. What is the method to include types other than the standard Int, String, Array, etc...

I am using Spark 2.1.0 on Amazon EMR.

Here some related questions I've referenced:

[How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440461/how-to-define-schema-for-custom-type-in-spark-sql)

[Spark UDF error - Schema for type Any is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392900/spark-udf-error-schema-for-type-any-is-not-supported)

Comment: What is `wanted()` in your example ?

Comment: @himanshulllTian Sorry that is the database with the columns c1, c2, c3, etc.

Comment: Have you considered accpeting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should define `Point` as a case class

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)
```

or if you wish

```
case class MyPoint(x:Double,y:Double) extends com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point(x,y)
```

This way the schema is inferred automatically by Spark

Comment: Doing this I get the following error:

`case class myPoint has case ancestor geotrellis.vector.Point, but case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes.`